# Typeahead js with Bloodhound- this.source is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm following [this example](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#bloodhound) for `typeahead.js` using `Bloodhound` to the T, but I'm getting a javascript error. What am I missing?

HTML: (.net razor view)

```
@Scripts.Render(Links.Scripts.typeahead_bundle_js) 
@Styles.Render(Links.Content.typeahead_min_css)
<input id="myInput" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var data = ["abce", "abcd", 'def', 'abcdef'];
    var bh = new Bloodhound({
        local: data,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });
    //bh.initialize(); //this wasn't in the example, adding it had no effect

    $('#myInput').typeahead({
        highlight:true
    },
    {
        name: "testData",
        source: bh
    });
});
```

gives the error in `typeahead.bundle.js`:

> this.source is not a function

Answer (score 16):

This one gave me a hard time too, because, same as you, I was doing everything to the letter as in the example... I took me a while to check the exact version of the lib that I use and compare it to the one in the example. I was using the typeahead.js 0.10.5 packaged in the 'twitter-typeahead-rails' gem, and in the [examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) the version used is typeahead.js 0.11.1.

As soon as I switched the version, everything started working as it should. There was even no need to re-map the array of strings into array of objects or to call ttAdapter on the source. Your code will probably work the way you posted it too...

---

Quote from twitter-typeahead [changelog](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for the version 0.11..0:

> ...There are bunch of API changes with this release so don't expect
>   backwards compatibility with previous versions. There are also many
>   new undocumented features that have been introduced. Documentation for
>   those features will be added before v1 ships. ...

Comment: Note: this still applies in 2018 since the version is still 0.11.1. Also, if you're using Nuget, the version is 0.10.1 - so get the most recent version from their website.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `source: bh.ttAdapter()` rather than `source: bh`

Comment: this got me halfway there, but all the results are just saying `undefined`, any ideas with that?

Comment: The way I usually do it is to use a `displayKey` option to the call to `typeahead`, but that's for referencing keys of objects. Maybe make your `data` array an array of objects with a `value` prop and pass a `displayKey: 'value'` to typeahead

Comment: I tried to do that but had no luck, would you mind posting a full example of that in the answer?

Comment: You can convert data into array of objects this way `data = data.map(function(_, i){ return {'value': data[i]}; });`

Comment: I think both the responses are good, but version 1.11.0, as @bosskovic suggests, has other bug, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746885/typeahead-js-not-returning-all-results) , so I solved the problem keeping version 1.10.5 and used this response to solve my problem.

Comment: I am using version 0.11.1. I am able to use typeahead on 2 of my form controls. However, I am not able to use it on the 3rd control (all 3 controls are on the same page). Source of these input's typeahead is based on ajax. See this http://imgur.com/a/WyqIK You can see add-enquiry.php:404 & 423 lines. Data of line 404 works well, but data of line 423 doesn't. It's very strange!