# typeahead.js not returning all results

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, typeahead.js

I'm having troubles getting typeahead.js to return/render all my results on my page. Here is my code:

```
var places = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/api/place/?country={{ country.id }}&name=%QUERY'
        , transform: function (data) {
            return data.response;
        }
        , wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});

var selected = false;
$('.typeahead-place').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2
},
{
    name: 'places',
    displayKey: function (obj) {

        if (obj.url != null && obj.url.length && (obj.street == null || obj.street.length == 0)) {
            return obj.name + " (Online store)";
        }

        return obj.name + " (" + obj.street + ", " + obj.city + ", " + obj.postcode + ")";
    },
    source: places
});
```

Example query of `Punn` gives me back the JSON from the server as:

```
{
    "response": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "Punnitse ja Säästä 2",
                "street": "Simonkenttä, Simonkatu 9",
                "city": "Helsinki",
                "postcode": "00100",
                "url": "http://www.punnitse.fi/"
            },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "Punnitse ja Säästä 3",
        "street": "Simonkenttä, Simonkatu 9",
        "city": "Helsinki",
        "postcode": "00100",
        "url": "http://www.punnitse.fi/"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "Punnitse ja Säästä 4",
        "street": "Simonkenttä, Simonkatu 9",
        "city": "Helsinki",
        "postcode": "00100",
        "url": "http://www.punnitse.fi/"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Punnitse ja Säästä Kamppi",
        "street": "Simonkenttä, Simonkatu 9",
        "city": "Helsinki",
        "postcode": "00100",
        "url": "http://www.punnitse.fi/"
    }
    ]
}
```

Right now this renders as so:

[image]

Answer (score 25):

This appears to be a [well-known bug](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1218) of the new version of `typeahead.js`. In order to make your code working correctly, you'd rather switch to version **0.10.5** or lower, and slightly transform your code:

```
var places = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/api/place/?country={{ country.id }}&name=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function(data) {      // <-- should use `filter`
            return data.response;
        }
    }
});

places.initialize();                  // <-- initialise suggestion

$('.typeahead-place').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2
}, {
    name: 'places',
    source: places.ttAdapter(),       // <-- get adapter as a source
    displayKey: function(obj) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/uszcp6j3/

---

Alternatively, if you want to stick to the latest version, you can apply [the following **patch**](https://github.com/getyourguide/typeahead.js/commit/6fc8051fec273d0fa0c8a9340446aad07923c34c), which was released some time ago, to the source code of the `typeahead.js`.

Comment: There is bug in the patch ^^ should remove one more row inside typeahead.bundle.js : suggestions = suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered);

Comment: @StavBodik there is no more bug you mentioned

Comment: Wow, it's 2020 and this is STILL an issue. I just used the patch @VisioN linked above, and it works perfectly well.

Answer (score 14):

I just found the answer to this here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1232 as supplied by [louy](https://github.com/louy):

```
...
$('.typeahead-place').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2,
    limit: Infinity
},
...
```

...which is to say, you need to set the limit to the Javascript global **Infinity** property.  This totally works!

That said, it's a crime that they haven't patched the code yet—this bug has been known for *years* now.